# What will replace chess?

Tags: chess-variants

Chess is dying. That much should be obvious. As predicted by Capablanca and as concluded by Bobby Fischer.... These are not random cranks, these are two of the best players of all time, and here are some of the words they have used to describe the game they devoted their life to: *solved*, *dead*, *terrible*, *boring*.

Of course this destiny of chess is something that a lot of people playing right now are desperate to ignore and pretend isn't true, because if it were (and it is), what would that say about their own pathetic devotion to this game? All those years wasted on a board game about to whither away.

So, recognizing that this bias exists, I hope we can scare some of the butthurt deluded posters away, so that the objective and sensible people remain to answer the following question of mine:

**What is next**? What comes *after* Chess? Capablanca chess, Fischerrandom chess, or maybe something else? What will take over?

And, **when** will it happen? My best bet is that considering the advance of Alpha Zero, that there is going to be an immense surge of chess "players" who win by purely memorizing tactics given to them by Alpha Zero. So, the death of chess will surely be sped up now. Maybe within a decade or two?

Comment: On your level it's already solved but weaker players will still enjoy some fun and complexity of the game.

Comment: I am talking about the professional level. Who gives a damn what weaker players do? They play ludo as well, should we create a ludo stack exchange?

Comment: @Dalemiso [boardgames.se]

Comment: Saying that computers killed chess is like saying that cranes killed weightlifting.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing will replace chess, it will be played by millions around the globe for the centuries to come. The theory and approaches might evolve a bit, like endgame tables have changed the tournament rules in the past, but otherwise, for 90% of the players nothing has changed and nothing will change, it's still a square board and 32 pieces.

"decade or two?" -- yeah, right. The tic-tac-toe was "solved" by most people even before they learn to read, and it's still here and will be here forever.